# Nested classes in Less media queries

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I am working with media queries with LESS.
In fact, I have a question about nested classes that differ from media query to another. here is the code in html on mobile devices:

```
<li>
<a id="play" href="#"></a>
<a id="play" href="#"></a> 
<li>
```

whereas the code on desktop should be:

```
<li>
<div id="btnItem"> 
<a id="play" href="#"></a>
<a id="play" href="#"></a> 
</div>
<li>
```

So to summerize, the difference is the div tag in the desktop. How could I code this in CSS? Is this correct?

```
li{
  @media @desktop{
    div{
    }
  }
 a{
   @media @desktop{
   }
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use media query like `@media (max-width: 1070px) { li  > div { //Your style here}}`

Comment: It depends on what styles you actually want to apply to these tags. In a simple case you don't even need to do anything because `li a` selector (as you wrote it above) matches your `a` tag in both HTML snippets, (and same way `li div` or `li > div` will not have any effect on mobile version at all).